# onResume of new Fragment called before onPause in Android Oreo 8.0

Tags: android, fragment, android-8.0-oreo, fragment-lifecycle

I am facing trouble with android Oreo. My MainActivity has 4 fragments, which replace each other whenever the user presses tabs. Now the problem is, I am saving a value in a singleton instance in onPause. Whenever the user presses the next tab, onResume of that fragment is called before onPause, so I am not able to retrieve the value from the singleton correctly.

Comment: I recommend you to go through fragment & activity lifecycle refer this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I read,Still dont know why onPause is called after onStop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem with Fragment in oreo version.I created a separate app to check what lifecycle functions are called when we replace one fragment with other..Here is the log:

```
MainActivity onCreate ->
FragmentA oncreate ->
FragmentA oncreateView ->
MainActivity onStart ->
FragmentA onStart ->
MainActivity onResume ->
FragmentA onResume ->
Button Pressed;that replace fragment A with Fragment B
FragmentB onCreate ->
FragmentB onCreateView ->
FragmentB onStart ->
FragmentB onResume ->
FragmentA onPause ->
FragmentA onStop ->
FragmentA onDestroy ->
```

I was importing import android.app.Fragment.It worked when I replaced it with android.support.v4.app.Fragment .

Answer (score 6):

Please use setReorderingAllowed as false to get the normal fragment lifecycle.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
fragmentTransaction.setReorderingAllowed(false);
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setReorderingAllowed(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

**onResume should called before onPause.**
If you want to save something before starting fragment do it in onStart. If you want to save something before leaving fragment do it in onStop. 
 [More info on Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: I am talking about the case when one fragment is replaced by another..after 1st fragment onResume,when I press the other tab for replacing it with other fragment..1st fragment pause should have been called first and than 2nd fragment onResume

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: I have tried saving in onStop as well,It works perfectly fine in all android version except oreo

Comment: can you give me fragment implementation code and  lifecycle logcat?